# What Excel formula would help find the address of a value in a range without headings?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table of text values that don't have any top or side headers.
Is there a way to find the address of the cell in the area I'm searching?

The table of relevant values is from F7:AB18.  There are blank columns in between each column of values.  I have used VBA to do this, but this is something I'd like to know how to do with a formula as well, if possible.  I understand INDEX & MATCH are used to find a position, but usually they have headers to assist.

[image: Table of text values]

Comment: You can use index/match on a multi-column range. Can you give an example of what you'd like to see given this data?

Comment: @Mockman - I'm trying to retrieve the address of the cell from the lookup value.  I have another range further down the tab that uses the UNIQUE formula to pull these text values from their respective tabs, then I use VBA to transfer them to that table.  I suppose some combination of ADDRESS with some form of XLOOKUP or INDEX-MATCH would do it, but I can't get the right combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[image]

Formulas from cells `O3:O6`

```
{=SUM((D2:L14=O2)*1)}
{=SUM(ROW(D2:L14)*(D2:L14=O2))}
{=SUM(COLUMN(D2:L14)*(D2:L14=O2))}
=IF(O3=1,ADDRESS(O4,O5,1),"Multiple occurences")
```

Formulas in `{}` are [array formulas.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

There is all-in-one formula in `O7` cell:

```
{=IF(SUM((D2:L14=O2)*1)=1,ADDRESS(SUM(ROW(D2:L14)*(D2:L14=O2)),SUM(COLUMN(D2:L14)*(D2:L14=O2)),1),"Multiple occurences")}
```

Comment: I appreciate both answers, however this one allowed for a precise match in the event of similar text values.  I found with using LARGE/AGGREGATE & FIND it would mix up MIAG with MIA.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want the address, but you can try (with your lookup string in `H1`, and `myRange` refers to the range to search):

```
=ADDRESS(
      AGGREGATE(14,6,FIND(H1,myRange)*ROW(myRange),1),
      AGGREGATE(14,6,FIND(H1,myRange)*COLUMN(myRange),1))
```

[image]

And it doesn't matter if there are blank rows/columns in `myRange`.